# ggplotly & Plotly missing values when I expand window

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a shiny app and using plotly and ggplotly. For some reason when I expand the size of the window, the plot loses some of the data points. Your help is much appreciated. 
[image]
[image]

```
 dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "calendar",
          fluidRow(width = 12,
                   column(width = 8, 
                   box( width = NULL, height = 400, 
              title = "Yang Zhang Estimator", solidHeader = T, status = "danger",

              plotlyOutput("yang_zhang", height = "320px")
            )) ...  


     server <- function(input, output) {

   spy = getSymbols("SPY", from = Sys.Date()-100, to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign =F)

   yz_vol = reactive({
   volatility(spy, n = as.numeric(input$slider_yz), calc = "yang.zhang", N = 252, 
   mean0 = F)
  })

   output$yang_zhang = renderPlotly({
   plot_ly(as.data.frame(yz_vol()), x = as.Date(index(yz_vol())), y = 
   as.numeric(yz_vol()), type = "scatter")

  }) 


 }
```

Comment: what do u use to expand the size of the window?

Comment: just my cursor. Is there a better alternative than plotly for interactive graphs?

Comment: Personally I dont like plotly because for large values it can be very slow, i primarely using highcharter, dygraphs and billboarder packages

Comment: Thanks I'll give those a try